# Moshi and Retrofit2: Unable to read service response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I'm trying to read a json response from a webservice, but without success.
This is the json i receive:

```
{
  "rsp": {
          "@code": "0",
          "@message": ""
       },
  "listOfStrings":[]
}
```

And this is relative data class where i parse response

```
data class Response(
    val rsp : Rsp,
    val listOfStrings : List<String>
)

data class Rsp(
    @Json(name = "@code")
    val code : String,
    @Json(name = "@message")
    val message : String
)
```

But it seems that moshi for some reason it's not able to parse json into object, because i always get Response object with all null fields.

So what's wrong? May the "@" character of json response fields cause problems?

**UPDATE**

Now i can parse correctly response by change @Json annotation into @field:Json:

```
data class Rsp(
    @field:Json(name = "@code")
    val code : String,
    @field:Json(name = "@message")
    val message : String
)
```

But i'm curious to know why it works.

Comment: because you haven't marked the `rsp` with proper `json` namings

Comment: Sorry, that was a Typo error, the json element and relative class had the same naming

Comment: oh, than you don't need any answer? In that case you can close it, or just delete it.

Comment: nono, i still need an answer, i always got null fields (I've just edit my question with correct class naming).

Comment: can you please add the dependencies of moshi that you are using?

Comment: Is it something you want to handle the null response?

Comment: The Update with the @field:Json annotation was the working solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

@field:Json is required if you want moshi-kotlin to work with proguard according to the discussion here: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/315

Answer (score 0):

Try this model and let me know if it works:

```
@Parcelize
data class Response(
    @Json(name = "rsp")
    val rsp: Rsp,
    @Json(name = "listOfStrings")
    val listOfStrings: List<String>
) : Parcelable {
    @Parcelize
    data class Rsp(
        @Json(name = "@code")
        val code: String,
        @Json(name = "@message")
        val message: String
    ) : Parcelable
}
```

Edit:
If it didn't work, try to add back-slash behind those field names that have `@`.

Like: `@Json(name = "\@code")`.

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION GOT UPDATE:**
You need to add `moshi-kotlin` dependency and then using `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory`

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    // ... add your own JsonAdapters and factories ...
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```

Then moshi couldn't ignore `@Json`.

Comment: i always got null response fields

Comment: @giozh With exact configuration, networking, try to fetch this https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums, and see if you can get data or not;;; And be sure that you have this problem on debug build variant without the proguard, and R8 is disabled;;; Be sure `.add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())` is the last added adapter;;; OOr use codegen: `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)`

Comment: I've found a solution, I think is something about Moshi on Kotlin with @Json annotation (in my other projects i don't use annotations on fields because they don't have "@" at the beginning). I edit my question with the solution i found.

Comment: @giozh You need to add `moshi-kotlin` dependency and add this `.add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())`. Then moshi couldn't ignore `@Json`. But thanks for sharing that solution